# Запрос SQL на сравнение двух таблиц с условием

Tags: sql

Есть 2 таблицы

Первая таблица: Customers (id, name, city, salesman_id)

Вторая таблица: Salesman  (id, name, city, commission)

Нужен запрос на получение всех имен Customers, у которых Salesman.commission от 0.10 до 0.20

Думаю, что так

```
SELECT customers.name WHERE Customers.salesman_id = Salesman.id WHERE 
Salesman.commission FROM 0.10 TO 0.20
```

Если не прав - помогите написать правильный SQL-запрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да влоб хотя бы...

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.name
FROM customers c, salesman s
WHERE c.salesman_id = s.id
  AND s.commission BETWEEN 0.10 AND 0.20
```

или через коррелированный подзапрос

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.name 
FROM customers c
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1
               FROM salesman s
               WHERE c.salesman_id = s.id
                 AND s.commission BETWEEN 0.10 AND 0.20 )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select distinct name 
from customers 
where salesman_id=any(
                    select id 
                    from salesman where commissions between 0.10 and 0.20
)
```

Ну или, если `=any` не поддерживается, то заменить на `in`

И, да, найти Грабера/Грубера "Понимание SQL". Может и устарел, но как учебник для начинающего вполне подойдет.

Comment: Спасибо. А если нужно учитыватб 0.10 и 0.20, то написать between 0.9 and 0.21 или есть какой-то специальный оператор?

Comment: Вообще-то between *включает* в себя границы.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы написал так:

```
SELECT Customers.name FROM Customers 
    LEFT JOIN Salesman ON (Customers.salesman_id = Salesman.id)
    WHERE Salesman.commission >= 0.10 AND Salesman.commission <= 0.20;
```